# Configuring Kubernetes Ingress Nginx to Preserve Client IP Address from Cloudflare Worker

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Regarding my Kubernetes setup, I am using the Nginx Ingress controller. To handle incoming requests, I utilize a Cloudflare worker to interact with my Kubernetes cluster. The worker sends a request with the following header:

X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxx2.xxx2.xxx2.xxx2

In this header:

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx represents the real IP address.
xxx2.xxx2.xxx2.xxx2 represents the Cloudflare worker IP address.

However, upon inspecting the pods inside the Kubernetes cluster (tcpdump), I notice that the headers received are as follows:

X-Real-IP: xxx2.xxx2.xxx2.xxx2
X-Forwarded-For: xxx2.xxx2.xxx2.xxx2
X-Original-Forwarded-For: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxx2.xxx2.xxx2.xxx2

I want to ensure that the actual client IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) is available inside the pods by the X-Forwarded-For header. How can I achieve this?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress2
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "100m"
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 300s
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 300s
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 300s
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
spec:
  rules:


    - host: test.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: myservice
                port:
                  number: xxxx


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: default
data:
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
    compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"
    use-proxy-protocol: "true"
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

You need to override nginx conf file https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/

Or have a config map like:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
  enable-real-ip: "true"
  compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.7.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```

Comment: The config-map option is best.